# All of a sudden, when updating the packages in my app using npm install, I get the following error

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js

```
module.exports = async process =\> {
^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
> at Module.\_compile (module.js:542:28)
> at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
> at Function.Module.\_load (module.js:438:3)
> at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
> at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
> at Object.\<anonymous\> (C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js:2:1)
> at Module.\_compile (module.js:570:32)
The current node version is 6.9.2`
```

Comment: Update node.  [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application) lists a pre-requisite version of 16.0 or higher.  You are on 6.9.2 according to the error message

Comment: the original formatting is entirely unreadable.  I simply surrounded the error in a [code block](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks) that makes it appear like it would in your IDE or terminal.  Please don't revert again :)

Answer (score -1):

I tried modifying Version as you cotoe and rerun:

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\cs-verse\node_modules@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}